# Is there an analogue of the hopf fibration for the hemisphere off $S^3$?

Tags: fiber-bundles, spherical-geometry, hopf-fibration

The Hopf fibration represents the 3-sphere $S^3$ as the circle $S^1$ fibred over the 2-sphere $S^2$. Does a similar construction exist for the hemisphere of $S^3$?

Answer (score 1):

The hemisphere is contractible so any fiber bundle over it would be trivial.

Comment: I would say that as the hemisphere is contractible it cannot be a circle bundle..

Comment: Ah ok, I thought he meant bundles over the hemisphere.